# Form submission verification through Ruby script

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a file which has a form the following HTML code:

```
<label for="subject">Subject</label>* : <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text">
<br>    
<label for="message">Message</label>* : <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
<br>
<input name="name" id="name" value="" type="hidden">
<input value="Submit Ticket" onclick="submitTicket()" type="button">
```

After I submit the form, the respective ticket will be in a table which has the following HTML code:

```
<table class="list" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr class="messagelist">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</a></th>
        <th>Subject</a></th>
        <th>Owner</a></th>
        <th>Priority</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_row">
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><a href="index.html?ID=14" class="trackingcode">14</a></td>
        <td class="name">X</td>
        <td class="subject">Test1</td>
        <td class="owner">AB</td>
        <td class="priority">High</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_row">
        <td>2.</td>
        <td><a href="index.html?ID=22" class="trackingcode">22</a></td>
        <td class="name">Y</td>
        <td class="subject">Test2</td>
        <td class="owner">CD</td>
        <td class="priority">Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_row">
        <td>3.</td>
        <td><a href="index.html?ID=31" class="trackingcode">31</a></td>
        <td class="name">Z</td>
        <td class="subject">Test3</td>
        <td class="owner">EF</td>
        <td class="priority">Medium</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_row">
        <td>4.</td>
        <td><a href="index.html?ID=42" class="trackingcode">42</a></td>
        <td class="name">A</td>
        <td class="subject">Test4</td>
        <td class="owner">GH</td>
        <td class="priority">High</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_row">
        <td>5.</td>
        <td><a href="index.html?ID=34" class="trackingcode">34</a></td>
        <td class="name">B</td>
        <td class="subject">Test5</td>
        <td class="owner">IJ</td>
        <td class="priority">Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_row">
        <td>6.</td>
        <td><a href="index.html?ID=43" class="trackingcode">43</a></td>
        <td class="name">C</td>
        <td class="subject">Test6</td>
        <td class="owner">KL</td>
        <td class="priority">Medium</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I am writing a RUBY code for the above form and ticket. I want to verify the submitted form and ticket with respect to subject `Test1`. Based on the subject, I want to click the ID link of `Test1`. 
Could anyone please help how to do this?

Here is what I tried:

```
    require 'watir'

    browser.tds(:class, 'list_row').each do |tds_row|
        if tds_row.text =~ /Test1/
            tds_row.a(:href, 'index.html').click
        end
    end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're not sure, but did you try? If not, why? If so, where is your code showing your attempt? Please read "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)".

Comment: @theTinMan, Sorry. I just put the code which I tried

Comment: So the fact that you're using the browser test automation tool [tag:Watir] is important, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, I am using watir

Comment: @theTinMan, I tried my best what I can do

Comment: @MarkThomas, I tried my best what I can do

Comment: Can I get any solution?

Comment: As to what you can do: (1) add the [tag:watir] tag. This way people who work with the tool will see your question. (2) Provide the exact response you're getting, even if (especially if) it is an error message. (3) be patient. Not all questions are answered immediately.

Comment: Ya ya sorry. Thanks

Comment: "I tried my best what I can do", well, we appreciate when you do, but we also have to judge, based on what's supplied in a question, whether there's sufficient information to answer correctly. It's important to know that SO isn't about answering the question of the person asking, it's about creating a reference book for others searching for a similar solution in the future. That's why we expect certain things such as clear evidence of effort, code summary, needed input and expected output, it helps others solve their problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the table rows, and element of the iterated row will be a table cell.  Then, you can examine the text of that cell.  If the value of the 4th cell is the one you're looking for (i.e. "Test1"), then click the link in the second cell, and break out of the iteration.  Here's a contrived example:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto("http://some_url")

b.button(:value => "Submit Ticket").click
b.trs.each do |tr|
  if tr[3].text == "Test1"
    tr[1].a.click 
    break
  end
end
b.close
```

It's still clunky and fragile, so it might be better to target the cells based on their class attributes.

Also--in your watir example--it looks like you are trying to locate table cells based on the parent row's class attribute (i.e. `browser.tds(:class, 'list_row')` instead of `browser.tds(:class, 'list_row')`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the HTML is well marked-up, iterating through the rows is more complicated than it has to be. It would be easier to find the specific subject cell and then navigate to its parent row.

```
# Find the cell with the specific subject text
subject = browser.td(class: 'subject', text: 'Test1')

# Get the row
row = subject.parent

# Click the tracking code link
row.link(class: 'trackingcode').click
```